# is $x^n$ uniformly convergence on $[0,1)$

Tags: uniform-convergence

So I know $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not uniformly convergence on $[0,1]$ since

\begin{equation}
    f_n(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ x<1 \\
      1, & \text{if}\ x=1
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

and $f_n(x)\longrightarrow f(x)=0$, but what about when the domain is being reduced only to $[0,1)$? Is it still not uniformly convergence? If yes or no, why?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f_n\to f=0$ uniformly, what must happen to $$\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,1)}f_n(x)$$ as $n\to\infty$? What does happen to it?

Comment: I'm not sure, so please correct me if I'm wrong.


Since $f_n$ is continuous, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $lim_{x \to 1^-} f_n(x)=f_n(1)=1$, which means it is $f_n$ is not uniformly convergence, _but_ I am not sure I am allowed to assume $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and not look at both limits ($n\rightarrow\infty$ and $x\rightarrow1^-$) at the same time.

Comment: @Flechs You're thinking too many steps away from the definitions. Think about what the definition of "$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$" really says, in terms of $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$.